# pyplot Reverse x axis and reverse table subplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, reverse

When I reverse the x axis in pyplot the accompanying table does not get effected. How can i reverse the display of the table elements?

```
ax=ep.plot(kind='bar',table=True).invert_xaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if tables ever know about  the axes direction.  I would just reverse the data before you pass it to the tables.

Comment: Thanks, I have since gone that direction of reversing the data before plotting and now I am wrapping my head around the machine state and OO interface of matplotlib. It's all there, I just need to learn the namespaces. Just like python to have a small hurdle explode into a research project but it seems to be the best way to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it ...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# get the data ... note the order ...
data = [4.77, 5.52, 5.93, 6.29, 6.0, 6.95, 7.7, 9.44, 10.94, 12.35, 13.45]
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data})

# referse the dataframe
df = df[::-1]

# ... and plot ...
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',table=True, figsize=(8,4)) # bar plots are categorical
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) # table heading and x-labels over-printing
plt.show()
```

Which yields ...

[image: chart generated by the above code]

And if we reverse it again ...

```
df = df[::-1]
```

We get ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I simply use:

```
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

for the "x" axe, or

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

for the "y" axe.
Without change the dataframe order.

Hope it helps.